# Color-coding numbers dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, c#, algorithm, colors

I have a sequence of elements each with their own ID. The IDs are running from 1...n. I want all elements which share an ID to be displayed in the same color.

I know I can do something like define an array of colors for each number, but this will be static and I really don't know how many numbers I will have.

So far I have done this:

```
private object getIntColorString(int IDNum)
{
    return IDNum.ToString("X6");
}
```

But I didn't think it through, as the difference between colors is too small. So then I did this:

```
private object getIntColorString(int eventTrainingProgramID)
{
    int colorCode = eventTrainingProgramID * 100; 
    return colorCode.ToString("X6");
}
```

However, this produces to many recurrences of the same color.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @LuigiCortese int.Max ...

Comment: so you need... 0x7fffffff different colors? Or how many different values can you have at once?

Comment: well if you put it that way .. then yeas.. but it will be okay to repeat the same color ... i can handle with half or even 1/4 of int.MAX ...

Comment: You can have a list of distinct colors (red, green, blue, etc.) and a dictionary to assign them to a certain id (`Dictionary<int,int>`, id and index of color). When there are too many ids you can start reusing colors, perhaps with some variations (either style or changing rgb of given color slightly). Consider to provide user with possibility to choose colors or to be able to track specific id (draw it more bold when it's selected), etc.

Comment: First of all, how are you going to represent colors? Integers? What range of integers?

Comment: You can define all the colours on account of RGB values by converting the input numbers into them (e.g., 1->(0,0,1); 2->(0,0,2), etc. ). There are 256*256*256 possibilities what I guess that should be enough for the range of your inputs. Also converting from colors to numbers will be immediate (i.e., you can get the RGB information of any colour very easily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, colors can go from `000000` (black) to `ffffff` (white), so 16777215 different values.
Let's assume you need to map an int in the range [0,2147483647] (0 to Int.MAX)
to the range of colors [0,16777215].

First problem: if you have 16777217 or more elements at once, some color is going to be repeated. If you have 16777216 elements or less, you can map a different color to each ID.

If you know in advance the number of elements (`#ID` = 100, for example), you can start like this:

- `col0` (color if `ID0`) could be (16777215/`#ID`)*0
- `col1` (color of `ID1`) could be (16777215/`#ID`)*1
- `col2` (color of `ID2`) could be (16777215/`#ID`)*2

and so on, to guarantee the biggest possible difference between adjacent colors.

If you don't know in advance the number of elements, you could define `colorJump` as the smallest increment that makes two colors different to your eyes. In this way

- `col0` (color if `ID0`) could be 0
- `col1` (color of `ID1`) could be `col0`+`colorJump`
- `col2` (color of `ID2`) could be `col1`+`colorJump`

and so on

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use modulo ? Like `id % number_of_different_colors = colord_id` ?

Comment: well, in this way if you have two id, ID0=0 and ID1=1, colors will be adjacent, almost the same

Comment: It depends on the display order of IDs, I don't really know if that was implied in the question. If it's sorted, indeed.